# Http call to the graph and asynchronous pattern does not seems to work

Tags: power-automate

I'm triggering an HTTP call from a power automate workflow to the MS Graph.

The operation is a long operation (cloning a MS teams), and return HTTP 202, with the `Location` header.

The HTTP action has the `Asynchronous Pattern` option set to **yes**.

I'm expecting Power Automate to automatically handle the *wait for* long operation to be finished.

However, the http action returns the 202 code, and I have to do myself the plumbing (do until sleep pattern).

How to properly call MS graph long operation and properly wait for completion ?

FYI, here's a sample request I make:

- Method : `POST`
- URL : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/b78b07c8-9af3-4af9-b995-315c6b674da8/clone`
- Body :

  ```
  {
    "displayName": "Some new team",
    "mailNickname": "somenewteam",
    "partsToClone": "apps,tabs,settings,channels,members",
    "visibility": "private"
  }
  ```
- Headers :

  ```
  {
    "ContentType": "application/json"
  }
  ```
- Plus all authentication headers (handled by the http action itself):

  ```
  {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "tenant": "some guid",
    "audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "clientId": "some guid",
    "secret": "*sanitized*",
    "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
  }
  ```

In comparison, using the option to call other long workflows (with http trigger and final "http response" action) works as expected